# Convert GMT time to local time in Gutenberg Block Editor

Tags: block-editor, date, date-time

I'm wondering if I can use any of the functions listed in the [@wordpress/date](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-date) package to convert a GMT date to a date in the user's locale.

For example, this GMT datetime `2023-06-20 17:46:00` would be `2023-06-20 19:46:00` in Europe/Vienna (GMT+2), the timezone I configured in Settings/General.

Converting the latter to the first is fairly simple via `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s','2023-06-20 19:46:00')`, but is there a *WordPressy* way to do it vice versa instead of having to use `moment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I can use any of the functions listed in the
> [@wordpress/date](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-date)
> package to convert a GMT date to a date in the user's locale.

Yes, you can **use the `dateI18n()` function**.

However, the **source date** (i.e. the 2nd parameter for the above function) *by default uses the time zone of the user's device*, so the source date should include the time zone even if it's UTC/GMT (+00:00). Secondly, the date should be a valid RFC2822 or ISO date [as documented here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), e.g. an ISO 8601 date like `2023-06-20T17:46:00Z`.

And for UTC dates, you could simply make use of the `moment.utc()` function, e.g. `moment.utc( '2023-06-20 17:46:00' )`.

So here are some examples on using `dateI18n()`, that were tried & tested working with WordPress v6.0 and the Europe/Vienna time zone or UTC +02:00:

- Example 1 — Convert from UTC to whatever the site's time zone or UTC offset:

  ```js
  const date1 = dateI18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P', moment.utc( '2023-06-20 17:46:00' ) );
  // Sample output: 2023-06-20 19:46:00 +02:00

  const date2 = dateI18n( 'l, F d, Y @ H:i:s P', moment.utc( '2023-06-20 17:46:00' ) );
  /* Sample output based on the user's/site's locale:
   * English  - Tuesday, June 20, 2023 @ 19:46:00 +02:00
   * Italiano - martedì, Giugno 20, 2023 @ 19:46:00 +02:00
   * Korean   - 화요일, 6월 20, 2023 @ 19:46:00 +02:00
   */
  ```
- Example 2 — Convert *from a specific UTC offset* (e.g. +03:00) to whatever the site's time zone or UTC offset:

  ```js
  const date1 = dateI18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P', '2023-06-20T17:46:00+03:00' );
  // Sample output: 2023-06-20 16:46:00 +02:00
  ```
- Example 3 — Convert from UTC *to a specific UTC offset* (e.g. -04:00) or time zone (e.g. America/New_York):

  ```js
  const date1 = dateI18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P', moment.utc( '2023-06-20 17:46:00' ), '-04:00' );
  const date2 = dateI18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P', moment.utc( '2023-06-20 17:46:00' ), 'America/New_York' );
  // Sample output of date1 and date2 above: 2023-06-20 21:46:00 +04:00
  ```

Comment: PS: The `date()` function in `@wordpress/date` would or might also give the same output, but for localization, you should use `dateI18n()` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for the detailed answer, just what I was looking for :)